# Problems with special characters and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems adding values to a text column as soon as "special characters" are used, like inside `Ligat ha'Al`. I am using php to send variables into my database. Are there any ways to "clean" this variable or convert the characters to avoid errors when submitting the data? The column in my database is `utf8_unicode_ci`.

I have added `$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $username, $password);`, but the error still exists.

Please help! Thanks for that!

Comment: @Strawberry I have add the charset as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through, but that is not working

Comment: Which operating system

Comment: No idea, Sorry.